# How to clean brackets with gsub?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I made data scraping like table below, but I can't find solution to clean up this table vith GSUB. Namely I tried code like :

```
populous_table$Tax_GDP <- gsub("[:punct:]","",populous_table$Tax_GDP )
```

but this code can't clean brackets `[]` for number 7 Australia.
Can anyone help me ?

```
1 Afghanistan  6.4
2 Albania 22.9
3 Algeria 7.7
4 Angola 5.7
5 Argentina 37.2
6 Armenia 22.0
7 Australia 34.3 [2]
8 Austria 43.4
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this page](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/) to learn how you can improve your question to get better and faster answers.

Comment: What is the rule here? What kind of result do you expect to get? `7 Australia 34.3 [2]` > `7 Australia 343 2`?

Comment: I want only clean punctuation character e.g  7 Australia 34.3 [2] without [2].

Comment: There are `.`, `[` and `]` punctuation chars here. Do you actually want to say you want to remove `[2]` substring and obtain `7 Australia 34.3` as a result?

Comment: Exactly that. I want only see 7 Australia 34.3 as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
populous_table$Tax_GDP <- gsub("\\s*\\[\\d+]","", populous_table$Tax_GDP )
```

Or, if that `[digits]` substring is always at the end, add `$`:

```
populous_table$Tax_GDP <- gsub("\\s*\\[\\d+]$", "", populous_table$Tax_GDP )
```

The [`\s*\[\d+]` pattern](https://regex101.com/r/jJYK1h/1) means

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `]` - a `]` char.

See [R demo](https://ideone.com/vywDuK):

```
x <- c("1 Afghanistan  6.4", "2 Albania 22.9", "3 Algeria 7.7", "4 Angola 5.7", "5 Argentina 37.2", "Armenia 22.0", "7 Australia 34.3 [2]", "8 Austria 43.4")
gsub("\\s*\\[\\d+]", "", x) 
## => [1] "1 Afghanistan  6.4" "2 Albania 22.9"     "3 Algeria 7.7"     
      [4] "4 Angola 5.7"       "5 Argentina 37.2"   "Armenia 22.0"      
      [7] "7 Australia 34.3"   "8 Austria 43.4"
```